# Android Studio and WSL2

Tags: android-studio

I'm running Android Studio (Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1) on Win11. The project directories are stored in WSL2 (opensuse tumbleweed). I can open a project in Android Studio and set gradle(8.1.1, plugin 8.0.1) to use WSL JDK (Oracle OpenJDK 18.0.1). When the project is synced I get an URISyntacException:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\AndroidStudio\plugins\android\lib\android.jar
```

Obviously, java URI doesn't like the colon in the path. If the project is in Windows and used windows gradle and JDK, everything works find.
Is there any way to run Android Studio on Windows with project and jdk/gradle on WSL2?

What I tried:

- re-installed Android Studio
- cloned the repo into empty dir
- deleted .gradle directory
- invalidated caches in Android Studio
- deleted .idea and .gradle in the project dir

Expected the project to sync and build

Comment: *"run Android Studio on Windows with project and jdk/gradle on WSL2"* - ¿why would you want to do this? This seems to be an XY problem.

Comment: @user7860670 I'm working through the same setup. I like Linux terminal but have a Windows machine. Windows doesn't run Android Studio well inside of WSL. I really don't want to start living in DOS world again as it's a lot of Linux to mentally port.